# Why does my assembly code stop execution in the middle?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

I am writing some assembly code, and for some reason when executing the following instruction:

```
mov [ds:0x666c44], eax   (NASM)
```

the execution of the subroutine stops. 
The subroutine is called from a DLL that is loaded by my other application.
0x666c44 is the address of a global variable I want to change.

What can be the problem?

Comment: You're assuming that `0x666c44` is the correct offset to your global variable. Is `ds` also set properly? And is that global variable 32 bits in size?

Comment: Just before this line I made it read the value at that address and print it to me, and it prints the correct variable that I want to change. So I guess DS is set?

Comment: Is that the only place in your assembly code where you write to the same segment (the one referred to by `ds` here)? Oh, and what do you mean by _"execution of the subroutine stops"_? Does it cause a segmentation fault?

Comment: Right after this instruction I tried adding more prints, instructions that try to write to NULL and crash, everything. It stops executing the rest of the code, as if there was a jmp. No segmentation faults, but as I said, this is called by dllMain, not the main process, so maybe the DLL crashed and the process didn't?

Comment: It's probably due to the side effect of changing the global variable (i.e. your other threads depend on that value). As long as `0x666C44` is a valid memory location (and you have write access to it), then that instruction alone shouldn't cause the program to stop.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was actually simpler... That address
was in read-only memory (.rodata), but for some reason the whole 
application did not crash, only the .dll and with no warning.